# cv2.findContours() succeeds and fails on identical arrays

Tags: python, opencv

I've ran into very strange behavior with `cv2.findContours` where it both fails and succeeds executing code on two arrays which are identical.

First, I do some arbitrary image processing on an image and then receive my output, which is in grayscale. We assign the output to the variable `estimate`. `estimate.shape = (512, 640)`, as it is a grayscale image. I then proceed to save this image to disk with `cv2.imwrite('estimate.png', estimate)`, and this is where my code stars misbehaving.

First of all, I try to read the image from disk and process it using `cv2.findContours()` according to the [documentation on OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html). The code looks as follows,and it executes successfully:

```py
im = cv2.imread('estimate.png')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, 0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

This is working as expected. But now, let's try `cv2.findContours()` directly on the variable `estimate`, without needlessly saving to disk and reading from it:

```py
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(estimate, 127, 255, 0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

>>> error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\thresh.cpp:1659: error: (-210:Unsupported format or combination of formats)  in function 'cv::threshold'
```

Okay, the natural assumption here is that `imgray` is different from `estimate`. Let us check the data:

```py
type(imgray)
>>> numpy.ndarray
type(estimate)
>>> numpy.ndarray
imgray.shape
>>> (512, 640)
estimate.shape
>>> (512, 640)
np.all(estimate == imgray)
>>> True
```

Okay, so the arrays are identical in shape and values. What is happening here? We're applying `cv2.findContours()` to the exact same numpy.ndarray. It fails when the array is created directly, and it succeeds if it is created via `cv2.imread`?

I'm using opencv-python=4.6.0.66 and python=3.9.12

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [answer], [mre]. MRE requires input data. I don't see any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this. Turns out, despite looking the same, the problem was in the actual types of arrays.

`cv2.findContours()` takes an unsigned 8-bit integer array. Therefore, estimate needs to be converted: `estimate = estimate.astype(np.uint8)`.

This can be checked using `estimate.dtype` and `imgray.dtype`.